# cannot set values for variables in global structures?

Tags: c

```
struct ball{
    int a;int b;
};

struct ball x;
x.a = 10;   x.b = 20;

int main() {
    x.a = 25; x.b = 50;
    printf("%d %d\n",x.a,x.b);
}
```

Why won't this code work.Im trying to set struct ball x; as a global variable and then set the value of a and b.

This is the terminal error:

```
x.c:54:1: error: unknown type name 'x'
x.a = 10;   x.b = 20;
^
x.c:54:2: error: expected identifier or '('
x.a = 10;   x.b = 20;
 ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment

```
x.a = 10;
```

is an example of an expression statement.   Expression statements (a statement which evaluates an expression, with an observable effect) are only permitted within functions.

It is possible to initialise a `struct` when defining a variable.  For example;

```
struct ball x = {10, 20};
```

defines `x` (to be of type `struct ball`) and initialises its members (in order).   Variable definitions that do initialisation like this are not restricted to only being used in a function body.

For standard C (1999 standard and later) it is also possible to use designated initialisers.

```
struct ball x = {.a = 10, .b = 20};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct ball{
    int a;int b;
};

struct ball x;
x.a = 10;   x.b = 20;  <-- Invalid to have assignment instruction outside of function body

int main() 
{
...
return 0;
}
```

You intended to initialize the global variable. Yes, that is permitted and can be done as follows:

```
struct ball{
    int a;int b;
};

struct ball x = {10, 20};   <-- struct global variable initialization
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
struct ball{
    int a;int b;
};

struct ball x;
//x.a = 10;   x.b = 20;

int main() {
    x.a = 25; x.b = 50;
    printf("%d %d\n",x.a,x.b);
}
```

Comment: In other words, you can only _modify_ variables in a function. You can only initialize them outside.

Comment: Variables can be initialised at the point of definition, Arc676.  Variable definitions are not limited to only being outside functions.

Answer (score 1):

For global variable you are able to done the declaration part (struct ball x) and initialization part(int a = 0) only in outside of all functions.
Inside the functions only you are able to assign or modify the values for the global variables. So, only you are getting this error.